# CSS block-level vs inline container issue

Tags: html, css, webkit

Here is the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/aTBWh/**

the container is `id(div)` meaning it  inherits a `display:block` value from the browser, the two div's inside this container are classes. they both have `200px` and `300px` while the main container has `600px` width, so I thought when I floated one of the classes to the right, it should only consume `300px` from the whole container meaning the two div's should fit inside the container without one appearing above the other. there is no `clear:both` attribute.

if the container is an id, with 600px, then the classes nested inside it (specially when one is floated to right, they should fill the container.)

**in a nutshell** why is the green div class out of the container when it can clearly fit there, and **it is floated to the right?** I don't understand this problem.

codes: 
css

```
#content_canvas_container{
    background:#CCC; 
    min-height:200px; 
    border:1px solid red;
    width:600px;
}
.red{
    width:200px; 
    background:red; 
    height:140px; 
}

.green{
    width:300px; 
    background:green; 
    height:140px; 
    float:right;
}

/*PROPERTIES*/
.w90{width:98%} 
.m_auto{margin:auto; border:1px solid black}
```

html

```
<section id='content_canvas_container'>
 <div class='w90 m_auto'>
   <div class='red'> red </div>
   <div class='green'> green </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: **I already knew the answer, I just wanted to know why it was happening**

Comment: I experienced this a lot through coding, I found a simple fix and i  think this is why the problem is caused look at the example at the bottom.
  

    `div
      div1 + div2`



If you want to float one of the divs it needs to be at the start, for example if you float div2 you will end up having the same problem but if you float div1 you will not end up having the same problem, Why this is happening I have no idea but it most likely related to what i explained up there, Can't wait to figure it out =d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behavior.

The reason this is occurring is because the red `div` element is a `block` level element by default. Thus, in its current state, it will always appear on a new line regardless of whether it has a defined width or has floating sibling elements.

By floating or absolutely positioning an element, you are essentially removing it from the flow of the document, rendering `display:block` ineffective. Therefore you can solve this by either floating the red `div` element, or adding `display:inline-block` to it. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/87ywH/1/)

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/87ywH/)

```
.red {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I am not asking for solution. I am asking what is the cause/reason behind it.

Comment: I just need to remind you that, thy both have a fixed width which would override the default 100% width and allow them to exists inside the container. so, I don't think that is it

Comment: I thought assigning absolute width and floating changed the elements from being block level to being inline-block elements. This does not make much sense, I don't know how/why they did this though

Comment: @THOR Nope. Floating an element doesn't make its display property `inline`. It definitely may **seem** like it is, but it isn't. Regardless of that, the red `div` element is still a block level element, meaning it will appear on a new line.

Comment: Ok, good point **but** if "the red div element is still a block level element, meaning it will appear on a new line." then why does it loose it flow content and appear inside the parent container as if it was inline, only by floating it? that is the real paradox. It taken only `float:right;` to make it looks it's `display:block` behavior. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @THOR The element only loses its flow when it is absolutely positioned or floated. Just because the red `div` element is inside the parent container doesn't mean its inline, nor does it mean that its out of the flow. The fact of the matter is that the red `div` is a block level element unless its display property is changed. However, it essentially loses its block level **behavior** when it is floated.

Comment: Still it makes a lot less sense than I imagined an answer would give. But still thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Using `float:left` will allow other elements to wrap around it. ([CSS-float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float))

> **The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it**. A floating element is one where the computed value of float is not none.

```
.red{
    float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTBWh/1/)

To understand why other elements won't wrap around your div by default, read up on block-level elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements).

> "Block-level" is categorization of HTML elements, as contrasted with "inline" elements. Block-level elements may appear only within a  element. **Their most significant characteristic is that they typically are formatted with a line break before and after the element** (thereby creating a stand-alone block of content). That is, they take up the width of their containers.

By default your `div` elements are block-level until you specify otherwise. The link I referrenced gives a list of all the elements that are block-level by default.

Comment: I know that is how it is done. I am asking **WHY** it is happening.

Comment: But .class is always inline element. Even if it was a block element, setting the width of the that element should not make it a block element does it

Comment: Until you change the display of the element it will be a block-level element. Using `display:inline` will change it to an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because when you set a `float` to a box, it moves to the left or the right of the container (according with other complex rules, of course), but it's vertical offset from the top of the container can't be smaller than it would be if it wasn't floated.

Comment: Nope that wasn't it. I added a height to the parent container that is more than the two inside divs, and still does not work

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Read rules number five and six form specs. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float

Comment: funny enough, if you add overflow: hidden; to the container div, it encompasses both elements

Comment: Which one? I can't replicate. Which browser are you using? Can you make a quick Fiddle?

Comment: @CarloCannas Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/aTBWh/3/ The height of the container has changed

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought your problem was the right floated div moving down. If you want the container to fit the content, when the content may contain floated box, a solution is to add a clearfix at the bottom (you can even use pseudo elements), another is the one you described: set `overflow` to a value different to `visible`. In the last case, that changes the rule used to determine height of block boxes: see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-root-margin.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is making a decision based on what you are telling it to do.

You haven't specified a float on the red div, so it remains in flow and acts as a normal block level element does i.e. "push everything after me to the next row".

You then tell the green div to float right in it's container, so it shifts over to the right.

Comment: Ok, but .class divs always have inline behavior, don't they? and I even specified the width, so that should override the space constraints

Comment: only if you specify inline-block or float it in the css. By default, block level elements always act as block level elements, regardless of the class attribute

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `DIV` are block-level elements, it means they begin in new lines. In your example when floating `.green` to the right, `.red` element still takes 100% of horizontal space, and `.green` takes now 300px but it is pushed down because as a block level element it belongs to the next line. To avoid this behavior, you must transform `block` elements into `inline` elements.

So in this case if you would like to float `.green` to the right, `DIV` elements within the parent wrapper should be rendered as inline blocks instead of independent blocks, just adding this rule:

```
.m_auto div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Cheers.